# Trello get actions deletedComment,addCheckItem

Tags: api, trello

I am missing some actions inside `boards/actions` in the trello api documentation. 
When I add a checklist I can get the type `addChecklistToCard` but there is no action for addCheckItemToCard and no one for `removeCommentFromCard` is this true?
Hope there is a simple workaround or I just miss a simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those things cause actions to be created, but the types (`createCheckItem` and `deleteComment`) are not exposed by the API.

Comment: So it isn't possible at all? I want to build a autosync function for my program and kind of need the functionality.

Comment: @Wikunia You should consider using webhooks to find out about changes: https://trello.com/docs/api/webhook/index.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't use a webserver for my program it's totally working on a client.

Comment: @Wikunia Well if you're polling for changes anyway, is there any reason you can't just check checklists for new items/comment feeds for missing comments?

Comment: No I think that's what I need to do but it would be easier to only check the actions.